# Postgis geometry type = Geometry

Tags: qgis, postgis

Simply I've got a number of PostGIS layers that have a geometry type of Geometry, as a posed to point, line, polygon.

```
wkb_geometry geometry(Geometry,27700)
```

QGIS 2.0+ doesn't like this very much and wants me to set the geometry type and in general makes my PostGIS connect in QGIS slow.

How do I change the Geometry type to point for instance?

Si

Answer (score 3):

You could add a new geometry column to your table with the specified point/line/poly and then copy the geometry from the current geometry column.

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD COLUMN geom geometry(POINT,27700);
```